# EntityNotFoundException when "cascade deleting" parent entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a Symfony2 application which has following setup:

`Agencija`(Serbian word for Agency) entity has two types of `Slika` (Serbian word for Picture) entity - `$maliLogoSlika` and `$velikiLogoSlika`.

`Slika` entity is used to describe and handle pictures that will be uploaded through form. There are two fields of `Slika` type in `Agencija` and they are both mapped tho same entity, hence the same table. Both entities are mapped to MySQL tables.

Adding new `Agencija` entries works just fine, tables populate and files are added to filesystem, but deleting is the problem. When i try to delete one `Agencija` entry which has two mapped `Slika` entries, only thing that happens is that one file (the one mapped to `$maliLogoSlika`) is deleted from filesystem. All the tables remain untouched and the other file is not deleted.

Finally I get following error:

> Entity was not found. 500 Internal Server Error -
>   EntityNotFoundException

In profiler, under Doctrine i get this:

> - "START TRANSACTION" Parameters: { }  [Display runnable query] Time: 0.00 ms [  + Explain query ]
> - Shrink query  DELETE FROM    agencija  WHERE    id = ? Parameters: [11]  [Display runnable query] Time: 0.00 ms [  + Explain query ]
> - Shrink query  DELETE FROM    slika  WHERE    id = ? Parameters: [21]  [Display runnable query] Time: 1.00 ms [  + Explain query ]
> - Shrink query  SELECT    t0.id AS id1,    t0.naziv AS naziv2,    t0.path AS path3  FROM    slika t0 Parameters: { }  [Display runnable
>     query] Time: 1.00 ms [  + Explain query ]
> - Shrink query  DELETE FROM    slika  WHERE    id = ? Parameters: [22]  [Display runnable query] Time: 225.01 ms [  + Explain query ]
> - Shrink query  SELECT    t0.id AS id1,    t0.naziv AS naziv2,    t0.path AS path3  FROM    slika t0 Parameters: { }  [Display runnable
>     query] Time: 1.00 ms [  + Explain query ]
> - "ROLLBACK" Parameters: { }  [Display runnable query] Time: 23.00 ms [  + Explain query ]

The part I understand is tables being untouched - that's because transaction fails. Deleted file gets deleted because of the `@ORM\PostRemove()` annotation that triggers when first query finishes, even if transaction as whole fails.

The part I don't understand is, well, why I get the error? :) It occurres to me that it has something to do with two foreign keys in Agencija table pointing to same (Slika) table. Maybe the aliases need to be different?

**Agencija.php**

```
namespace Letovanje\AgencijaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Agencija
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="agencija", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="naziv_UNIQUE", columns={"naziv"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_agencija_slika1_idx", columns={"mali_logo_slika_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_agencija_slika2_idx", columns={"veliki_logo_slika_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Letovanje\AgencijaBundle\Entity\AgencijaRepository")
 */
class Agencija
{

    /**
     * @var \Letovanje\SlikaBundle\Entity\Slika
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Letovanje\SlikaBundle\Entity\Slika", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="veliki_logo_slika_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $velikiLogoSlika;

    /**
     * @var \Letovanje\SlikaBundle\Entity\Slika
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Letovanje\SlikaBundle\Entity\Slika", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mali_logo_slika_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $maliLogoSlika;

    //...
 }
```

**Slika.php** (which is basically same as Document entity in [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) example)

```
<?php

namespace Letovanje\SlikaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Slika
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="slika", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Slika
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

Delete action is called from controller (only relevant parts pasted here).

**DefaultController.php**

```
public function deleteAction($naziv){
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                           ->getRepository('LetovanjeAgencijaBundle:Agencija');
        $agencija = $repository->findOneByNaziv($naziv);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($agencija);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'success',
            'Agencija uspesno obrisana!'
        );

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('agencije'));

    }
```

and finaly two tables:

**agencija**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `letovanje`.`agencija` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naziv` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `je_aktivna` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `web_adresa` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `mali_logo_slika_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `veliki_logo_slika_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `naziv_UNIQUE` (`naziv` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_agencija_slika1_idx` (`mali_logo_slika_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_agencija_slika2_idx` (`veliki_logo_slika_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_agencija_slika1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mali_logo_slika_id`)
    REFERENCES `letovanje`.`slika` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_agencija_slika2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`veliki_logo_slika_id`)
    REFERENCES `letovanje`.`slika` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**slika**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `letovanje`.`slika` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naziv` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `path` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Too much code here. Please try to post only the relevant sections of your code. Otherwise, you may not get much help. It's a lot of sift through.

Comment: I removed irrelevant code as you suggested. Thing is, there is something going on "under the hood" that i can't figure out.